# Correct way for pointer alignment

Tags: c++, memory, memory-alignment

I have following code for pointer alignment

```
char *p = new char[1000];
//...
++p;
//...
int alignment = 4;
int extra_bytes = (size_t)p % alignment;

int *aligned_ptr = (int*)(p + (alignment - extra_bytes));
std::cout << ((size_t)aligned_ptr % alignment); //aligned
//...
```

I want know it is correct code for pointer alignment? If yes, can anyone here show the implementation which is better? (For example, using bitwise operations)

Comment: I don't know why there are down votes, it is a clear question with a definite answer and a code example.

Comment: Is this correct code, and if it is correct, please show me a better way? ??  If it's correct, then there wouldn't be a better way?

Comment: @Galik if this has a definite answer, then please provide it.  In my opinion, as it stands now, the question is a confusing mess.

Comment: @Claies I don't know how to provide a correctly aligned pointer but I know there are elements in the standard library to make this possible. If the question is confusing then people should at least ask the poster to clarify before downvoting/closevoting.

Comment: A few too many questions. You lose track of the returned value from new, so how do you delete it? (Avoid using new.) If you just want to get an aligned pointer, I would recommend you look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom Yes i know about losing returned value from new in code above. That is just example code. std::align needs 4 parameters and that generate some overhead which i dont need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer is aligned if your quotient is `0` after performing modulo operation *pointer mod alignment*.

This means that you can check (in C++11) using

```
#include <cstdint>
bool isAligned = ((reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(pointer) % alignment) == 0);
```

You can also do it using *bitwise operation* (only if alignment is a power of 2)

```
bool isAligned = ((reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(pointer) & (alignment - 1)) == 0);
```

However, the compiler will probably optimize that for you.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you don't actually need to actually cast the pointer to check its bits, since you can use the indices within the buffer. Consider using something like:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

// in case your compiler doesn't support C++11 `alignof`,
// it's easy to implement
#define ALIGNOF(T) (sizeof(alignof_helper<T>) - sizeof(T))
// or in GNU C, although it provides __alignof__ anyway
#define ALIGNOF_C(T) ({ struct alignof_c_helper { char c; T data; }; sizeof(alignof_c_helper) - sizeof(T); })
// but of course, macros are EVIL.
template<class T>
struct alignof_helper
{
    char c;
    // implicit padding since data must be aligned
    T data;
};

struct aligned_buffer
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> vec;
    size_t index;

    aligned_buffer(size_t sz = 0)
    : vec(sz)
    , index(0)
    {
    }

    template<class T>
    T *get(size_t count=1)
    {
        // malloc() and ::operator new() return normally-aligned memory
        static_assert(alignof(T) <= alignof(std::max_align_t), "no overaligned types without a special allocator");
        size_t offset = this->index % alignof(T);
        size_t start_index = this->index;
        size_t new_index, asize;
        if (offset)
        {
            start_index += alignof(T) - offset;
            if (!start_index) // overflowed
                throw std::length_error("how did you allocate that much? I'm impressed");
        }
        if (__builtin_mul_overflow(alignof(T), count, &asize) || __builtin_add_overflow(start_index, asize, &new_index))
        {
            throw std::length_error("ridiculous size");
        }
        if (new_index > this->vec.size())
        {
            throw std::length_error("insufficient reserved space");
        }
        this->index = new_index;
        return reinterpret_cast<T *>(&this->vec[start_index]);
    }
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(alignof(int) == ALIGNOF(int), "C++98 version");
    static_assert(alignof(int) == ALIGNOF_C(int), "GNU C statement-expression");
    static_assert(alignof(int) == __alignof__(int), "GNU C keyword");

    static_assert(alignof(int) == 4 && alignof(long long) == 8, "tests below assume a \"normal\" environment");
    aligned_buffer buf(16);
    *buf.get<char>() = 'A';
    auto a = buf.get<int>(2);
    a[0] = 123;
    a[1] = 456;
    try
    {
        buf.get<long long>();
        throw std::logic_error("code is wrong I guess?");
    }
    catch (std::length_error& e)
    {
    }
    // can still use the buffer
    *buf.get<char>() = 'Z';

    puts("everything is okay");
}
```

Modifying this code to allow safely resizing the underlying buffer, and thus worrying about pointer invalidation, is left as an exercise for the reader.